# Ubuntu can resolve DNS but cant PING our Download

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, domain-name-system, ping

I'm trying to make an ubuntu development server work.
All machines on the network (mac and windows) get internet and lan access but ubuntu only works on the lan.

I have two interfaces:
eth0 (static)
eth1 (dhcp, but virtual box bridges it to run a windows application server, wich has both lan and internet access)

my static configuration for eth0 is:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.1.1.101
netmask 255.0.0.0
network 10.1.1.0
broadcast 10.1.1.255
gateway 10.1.1.1

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

and here is the ipconfig of a windows machine wich has everything working with static setup:

```
ip: 10.1.1.100
netmask: 255.0.0.0
gateway: 10.1.1.1
```

routes on ubuntu server:

administrador@servidor-linux:~$ route -n

```
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 eth1
0.0.0.0         10.1.1.1        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth1
0.0.0.0         10.1.1.1        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
```

routes of a windows machine with everythin working:

```
route print
===========================================================================
Lista de interfaces
0x1 ........................... MS TCP Loopback interface
0x2 ...78 e7 d1 f2 67 7d ...... Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller - Miniporta do
 agendador de pacotes
0x3 ...c4 17 fe 09 3a e4 ...... Adaptador de rede Broadcom 802.11b/g - Miniporta
 do agendador de pacotes
===========================================================================
===========================================================================
Rotas ativas:
Endereço de rede          Máscara   Ender. gateway       Interface   Custo
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         10.1.1.1      10.1.1.106       25
         10.0.0.0        255.0.0.0       10.1.1.106      10.1.1.106       25
       10.1.1.106  255.255.255.255        127.0.0.1       127.0.0.1       25
   10.255.255.255  255.255.255.255       10.1.1.106      10.1.1.106       25
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0        127.0.0.1       127.0.0.1       1
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0       10.1.1.106      10.1.1.106       25
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255       10.1.1.106      10.1.1.106       1
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255       10.1.1.106               2       1
Gateway padrão:           10.1.1.1
===========================================================================
Rotas persistentes:
  Nenhuma
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I think that should be `network 10.0.0.0 broadcast 10.255.255.255` but I'm no expert.

Comment: It would be of interest to see your routing tables. `route -n` for linux, `ROUTE /N PRINT` (I think) for Windows.

Comment: just added the routes

Comment: installed network manager and internet still didnt work, but when i disabled one network interface everyting goes ok. How should I do to have static ip in eth0 and openbox bridge in eth1 ?

Answer (score 1):

Delete that route

```
0.0.0.0         10.1.1.1        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth1
```

Anything for the internet is forwarded via eth1 instead of eth0. Also try not to use so big netmasks , except for the cases that you are an ISP :p